# Using ASP.NET Core Identity for authenticating Controller usage

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-mvc, razor-pages, asp.net-core-3.1

I have been developing a asp.net core razor application and I have stuck to using views and models. However, I added a frontend framework so making HTTP request is used quite often so I thought I would test out the Web API in asp.net core by adding a controller and it is awesome how easy it is to pass usable json arrays to the frontend. My issue is I implemented the following code to my razor application's startup.cs to restrict any non logged in users from accessing any other pages or page models unless logged in:

```
            services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddCookie(cookieOptions => {
                cookieOptions.Cookie.Name = "UserLoginCookie";
                cookieOptions.LoginPath = "/Login/";
                cookieOptions.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
                cookieOptions.SlidingExpiration = true;
            });
```

This works great except the issue I am finding is my test HomeController is still accessible (url/home/index) even if I am not logged in. Is there a way to use the identity authentication I used for my razor pages to restrict access to the controller for only logged in users. Also, for an extra layer of security I wanted to store a variable server side for the logged in user's ID and integrated that into the controller so i can limit my queries to that user without letting it be a HTTP parameter which could then allow anyone to access other users data.

Answer (score 0):

Adding [Authorize] above the homecontroller class did the trick but not sure why I was required to use this tag to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

If you add [Authorize] on the whole controller it will prevent all the methods in that class to be accessible. Requires the specified authorization
In this case the CookieAuthenticationDefaults.
If you have more than one you can specify the name of the policy you want it to check for

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Administrator")]
```

Here is the AuthorizeAttribute class  for more information

```
using System;
namespace Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization
{
/// <summary>
/// Specifies that the class or method that this attribute is applied to requires the 
    specified authorization.
 /// </summary>
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple =true,  
  Inherited = true)]
public class AuthorizeAttribute : Attribute, IAuthorizeData
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="AuthorizeAttribute"/> class with 
        the specified policy. 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="policy">The name of the policy to require for authorization.</param>
    public AuthorizeAttribute(string policy)
    {
        Policy = policy;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the policy name that determines access to the resource.
    /// </summary>
    public string? Policy { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets a comma delimited list of roles that are allowed to access the resource.
    /// </summary>
    public string? Roles { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets a comma delimited list of schemes from which user information is constructed.
    /// </summary>
    public string? AuthenticationSchemes { get; set; }
}
```

}